# Convert a number in scientific notation to numeric format in Excel using a macro or VBA

Tags: excel, vba

[MS Excel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Excel) has eaten my head. It is randomly converting numbers into scientific notation format. This causes a problem when I load the file saved in tab delimited format into SQL Server. I know I can provide a format file and do lot of fancy stuff. But let's say I can't.

Is there a macro which loops over all the cells and if the number in a cell is in scientific notation format then it converts it to numeric format?

Say:

```
Input: spaces signify different cells.
1.00E13 egalitarian
```

Output after macro:

```
10000000000000 egalitarian
```

I am trying this in Excel 2007.

Comment: Excel holds all numbers in an appropriate binary format.  If space is limited it will display a long number in scientific notation but this does not affect the value held.  Make the column wider and it will switch to standard format.

Comment: Also cells formatted as General will display this notation for any number longer than ten digits, format as number and adjust the column width to make it as long as you wish.

Comment: The problem is now how the cells are displayed, but how they are saved as a text file. Please post the code that does the saving and then we can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a simple C# program to resolve this issue. Hope it's of use.

#### Input:

Input directory where files reside (assuming files are in .txt format).

#### Output:

Output directory where converted files will be spit out.

#### Delimiter:

Column delimiter.

#### The code

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConvertToNumber
{
    class Program
    {
        private static string ToLongString(double input)
        {
            string str = input.ToString().ToUpper();

            // If string representation was collapsed from scientific notation, just return it:
            if (!str.Contains("E")) 
                return str;

            var positive = true;
            if (input < 0)
            {
                positive = false;
            }

            string sep = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator;
            char decSeparator = sep.ToCharArray()[0];

            string[] exponentParts = str.Split('E');
            string[] decimalParts = exponentParts[0].Split(decSeparator);

            // Fix missing decimal point:
            if (decimalParts.Length == 1) 
                decimalParts = new string[] { exponentParts[0], "0" };

            int exponentValue = int.Parse(exponentParts[1]);

            string newNumber = decimalParts[0].Replace("-","").
                Replace("+","") + decimalParts[1];

            string result;

            if (exponentValue > 0)
            {
                if(positive)
                    result =
                       newNumber +
                       GetZeros(exponentValue - decimalParts[1].Length);
                else
                    result = "-"+
                     newNumber +
                     GetZeros(exponentValue - decimalParts[1].Length);


            }
            else // Negative exponent
            {
                if(positive)
                    result =
                        "0" +
                        decSeparator +
                        GetZeros(exponentValue + decimalParts[0].Replace("-", "").
                                   Replace("+", "").Length) + newNumber;
                else
                    result =
                    "-0" +
                    decSeparator +
                    GetZeros(exponentValue + decimalParts[0].Replace("-", "").
                             Replace("+", "").Length) + newNumber;

                result = result.TrimEnd('0');
            }
            float temp = 0.00F;

            if (float.TryParse(result, out temp))
            {
                return result;
            }
            throw new  Exception();
        }

        private static string GetZeros(int zeroCount)
        {
            if (zeroCount < 0)
                zeroCount = Math.Abs(zeroCount);

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            for (int i = 0; i < zeroCount; i++) sb.Append("0");

            return sb.ToString();
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Get Input Directory.
            Console.WriteLine(@"Enter the Input Directory");
            var readLine = Console.ReadLine();
            if (readLine == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(@"Enter the input path properly.");
                return;
            }
            var pathToInputDirectory = readLine.Trim();

            //Get Output Directory.
            Console.WriteLine(@"Enter the Output Directory");
            readLine = Console.ReadLine();
            if (readLine == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(@"Enter the output path properly.");
                return;
            }
            var pathToOutputDirectory = readLine.Trim();

            //Get Delimiter.
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the delimiter;");
            var columnDelimiter = (char) Console.Read();

            //Loop over all files in the directory.
            foreach (var inputFileName in Directory.GetFiles(pathToInputDirectory))
            {
                var outputFileWithouthNumbersInScientificNotation = string.Empty;
                Console.WriteLine("Started operation on File : " + inputFileName);

                if (File.Exists(inputFileName))
                {
                    // Read the file
                    using (var file = new StreamReader(inputFileName))
                    {
                        string line;
                        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
                        {
                            String[] columns = line.Split(columnDelimiter);
                            var duplicateLine = string.Empty;
                            int lengthOfColumns = columns.Length;
                            int counter = 1;
                            foreach (var column in columns)
                            {
                                var columnDuplicate = column;
                                try
                                {
                                    if (Regex.IsMatch(columnDuplicate.Trim(),
                                                      @"^[+-]?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?[E]([+-]?[0-9]+)$",
                                                      RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
                                    {
                                        Console.WriteLine("Regular expression matched for this :" + column);

                                        columnDuplicate = ToLongString(Double.Parse
                                                                           (column,
                                                                            System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Float));

                                        Console.WriteLine("Converted this no in scientific notation " +
                                                          "" + column + "  to this number " +
                                                          columnDuplicate);
                                    }
                                }
                                catch (Exception)
                                {

                                }
                                duplicateLine = duplicateLine + columnDuplicate;

                                if (counter != lengthOfColumns)
                                {
                                    duplicateLine = duplicateLine + columnDelimiter.ToString();
                                }
                                counter++;
                            }
                            duplicateLine = duplicateLine + Environment.NewLine;
                            outputFileWithouthNumbersInScientificNotation = outputFileWithouthNumbersInScientificNotation + duplicateLine;
                        }

                        file.Close();
                    }

                    var outputFilePathWithoutNumbersInScientificNotation
                        = Path.Combine(pathToOutputDirectory, Path.GetFileName(inputFileName));

                    //Create the directory if it does not exist.
                    if (!Directory.Exists(pathToOutputDirectory))
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(pathToOutputDirectory);

                    using (var outputFile =
                        new StreamWriter(outputFilePathWithoutNumbersInScientificNotation))
                    {
                        outputFile.Write(outputFileWithouthNumbersInScientificNotation);
                        outputFile.Close();
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine("The transformed file is here :" +
                        outputFilePathWithoutNumbersInScientificNotation);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This works fairly well in case of huge files which we are unable to open in MS Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Peter.
I updated your original work to:
1) take in an input file or path
2) only write out a processing statement after every 1000 lines read
3) write the transformed lines to the output file as they are processed so a potentially large string is not kept hanging around
4) added a readkey at the end so that console does not exit automatically while debuggging

```
    using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConvertScientificToLong
{
    class Program
    {
        private static string ToLongString(double input)
        {
            string str = input.ToString().ToUpper();

            // If string representation was collapsed from scientific notation, just return it:
            if (!str.Contains("E"))
                return str;

            var positive = true;
            if (input < 0)
            {
                positive = false;
            }

            string sep = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator;
            char decSeparator = sep.ToCharArray()[0];

            string[] exponentParts = str.Split('E');
            string[] decimalParts = exponentParts[0].Split(decSeparator);

            // Fix missing decimal point:
            if (decimalParts.Length == 1)
                decimalParts = new string[] { exponentParts[0], "0" };

            int exponentValue = int.Parse(exponentParts[1]);

            string newNumber = decimalParts[0].Replace("-", "").
                Replace("+", "") + decimalParts[1];

            string result;

            if (exponentValue > 0)
            {
                if (positive)
                    result =
                       newNumber +
                       GetZeros(exponentValue - decimalParts[1].Length);
                else
                    result = "-" +
                     newNumber +
                     GetZeros(exponentValue - decimalParts[1].Length);


            }
            else // Negative exponent
            {
                if (positive)
                    result =
                        "0" +
                        decSeparator +
                        GetZeros(exponentValue + decimalParts[0].Replace("-", "").
                                   Replace("+", "").Length) + newNumber;
                else
                    result =
                    "-0" +
                    decSeparator +
                    GetZeros(exponentValue + decimalParts[0].Replace("-", "").
                             Replace("+", "").Length) + newNumber;

                result = result.TrimEnd('0');
            }
            float temp = 0.00F;

            if (float.TryParse(result, out temp))
            {
                return result;
            }
            throw new Exception();
        }

        private static string GetZeros(int zeroCount)
        {
            if (zeroCount < 0)
                zeroCount = Math.Abs(zeroCount);

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            for (int i = 0; i < zeroCount; i++) sb.Append("0");

            return sb.ToString();
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Get Input Directory.
            Console.WriteLine(@"Enter the Input Directory or File Path");
            var readLine = Console.ReadLine();
            if (readLine == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(@"Enter the input path properly.");
                return;
            }
            var pathToInputDirectory = readLine.Trim();

            //Get Output Directory.
            Console.WriteLine(@"Enter the Output Directory");
            readLine = Console.ReadLine();
            if (readLine == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(@"Enter the output path properly.");
                return;
            }
            var pathToOutputDirectory = readLine.Trim();

            //Get Delimiter.
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the delimiter;");
            var columnDelimiter = (char)Console.Read();

            string[] inputFiles = null;

            if (File.Exists(pathToInputDirectory))
            {
                inputFiles = new String[]{pathToInputDirectory};
            }
            else
            {
                inputFiles = Directory.GetFiles(pathToInputDirectory);
            }

            //Loop over all files in the directory.
            foreach (var inputFileName in inputFiles)
            {
                var outputFileWithouthNumbersInScientificNotation = string.Empty;
                Console.WriteLine("Started operation on File : " + inputFileName);

                if (File.Exists(inputFileName))
                {
                    string outputFilePathWithoutNumbersInScientificNotation
                        = Path.Combine(pathToOutputDirectory, Path.GetFileName(inputFileName));

                    //Create the directory if it does not exist.
                    if (!Directory.Exists(pathToOutputDirectory))
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(pathToOutputDirectory);

                    using (var outputFile =
                        new StreamWriter(outputFilePathWithoutNumbersInScientificNotation))
                    {
                        // Read the file
                        using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader(inputFileName))
                        {
                            string line;
                            int lineCount = 0;
                            while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
                            {
                                String[] columns = line.Split(columnDelimiter);
                                var duplicateLine = string.Empty;
                                int lengthOfColumns = columns.Length;
                                int counter = 1;
                                foreach (var column in columns)
                                {
                                    var columnDuplicate = column;
                                    try
                                    {
                                        if (Regex.IsMatch(columnDuplicate.Trim(),
                                                          @"^[+-]?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?[E]([+-]?[0-9]+)$",
                                                          RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
                                        {
                                            //Console.WriteLine("Regular expression matched for this :" + column);

                                            columnDuplicate = ToLongString(Double.Parse
                                                                               (column,
                                                                                System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Float));

                                            //Console.WriteLine("Converted this no in scientific notation " +
                                            //                  "" + column + "  to this number " +
                                            //                  columnDuplicate);

                                            if (lineCount % 1000 == 0)
                                            {
                                                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("processed {0} lines. still going....", lineCount));
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                    catch (Exception)
                                    {

                                    }
                                    duplicateLine = duplicateLine + columnDuplicate;

                                    if (counter != lengthOfColumns)
                                    {
                                        duplicateLine = duplicateLine + columnDelimiter.ToString();
                                    }
                                    counter++;
                                }

                                outputFile.WriteLine(duplicateLine);

                                lineCount++;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("The transformed file is here :" +
                        outputFilePathWithoutNumbersInScientificNotation);

                    Console.WriteLine(@"Hit any key to exit");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An easier way would be to save it as a .csv file.  Then, instead of just opening the file - you go to the Data tab and select "from text" so that you can get the dialogue box. This way you can identify that column with the scientific notation as text to wipe out that format.  Import the file and then you can reformat it to number or whatever you want.